# how can I convert an objectect type to str? in python

Tags: python, pandas, string, object, integer

I'm trying to convert a dataframe with type: object to str with the methods: apply, astype, grouping all the 'o' type variables and convert them and creating functions to convert like this:

```
def to_str(value):
    try:
        return str(value)
    except:
        return None

df_final['Columna 1'] = df_final['Columna 1'].apply(to_str)
```

But the dataframe still being 'o' type. I'm doing this to try to replace a null value type 'o' to a null value type str or int, this to make a function that finds this values and tabular the data frame.

Comment: Maybe I don't quite understand your question but have you tried to use the `astype()` function? Or do you want to know how to apply it to the dataframe?

Comment: Because `object` dtype represents everything what is not numeric (float64, int64, ...). Please provide an example. `print(df.head(10).to_dict('list'))` could help.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are of type `object`. Here, first I make the column type `int` and print it, then I convert it to a `string` type. Checking the type with [dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html).

```
import pandas as pd

df_final = pd.DataFrame({'Columna 1': [1, 2, 3]})
    
df_final['Columna 1'] = df_final['Columna 1'].astype(int)
print(df_final.dtypes['Columna 1'])# type int

df_final['Columna 1'] = df_final['Columna 1'].astype(str)
print(df_final.dtypes['Columna 1'])# type object
```

You can also check for a string type through [is_string_dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_string_dtype.html).

```
from pandas.api.types import is_string_dtype

df_final['Columna 1'] = df_final['Columna 1'].astype(str)

print(is_string_dtype(df_final.dtypes['Columna 1']))#True
```